# How to calculate uncertainty in the sum of the predictions

Tags: r, lm

I am using dummy data to ask my question:

I have a linear model `y~x`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
theme_set(theme_pubr())
model <- lm(sales ~ youtube, data = marketing)
```

Let's assume I am predicting into a new dataset:

```
pred=predict(model,marketing[1:20,], interval="prediction")
```

I want to calculate the sum of all sales of predicted values (`sum(pred$fit)`) and also calculate the uncertainty in the estimate. I am a bit unsure how to calculate uncertainty
Am I correct to calculate this uncertainty by: `lwr.sum=(sum(lwr^2))^0.5` and `upr.sum=(sum(upr^2))^0.5`

UPDATE: I tried to calculate using my method, but my mean is not inside the `lwr.sum` and `upr.sum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predicted values will be *strongly* correlated because they are all based on the same two estimated coefficients (slope and intercept).

To reason through this, we need some notation.  Let $x_i$ be an array of $n$ new values of the explanatory variable `youtube`; let $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ be the coefficient estimates, so that the predicted value for $x_i$ is

$$\hat y_i  = \hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1 x_i,$$

and let $\Sigma$ be their variance-covariance matrix (obtainable in `R` with the function `vcov(model)`).

The sum of the predictions therefore is

$$\hat p = \sum_{i=1}^n \hat y_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1 x_i = n\hat\beta_0 + S_x\hat\beta_1$$

where I have written $S_x$ for the sum of the $x_i.$  The variance is

$$\operatorname{Var}(\hat p) = \operatorname{Var}(n\hat\beta_0) + \operatorname{Var}(S_x\hat\beta_1) + 2\operatorname{Cov}(n\hat\beta_0, S_x\hat\beta_1) = \pmatrix{n&S_x}\Sigma\pmatrix{n\\S_x}.$$

(The sum of the variances looks a little like the formulas proposed in the question; but usually the covariance term cannot be neglected: it will be zero only when the mean of the *original* data used for the estimates is zero.)

(I wrote this in matrix notation to indicate the generalization to multiple explanatory variables if you are doing multiple regression.)

The square root of $\operatorname{Var}(\hat p)$ is the standard error of this prediction.  Use it in the usual way to erect confidence or prediction limits around that value.

This `R` code shows the steps in detail: see the three lines at the end where `p.hat` and `se` are computed.  The is written to work without change for multiple regression.

```R
#
# Create some data.
#
X <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 19, by = 2)) # Explanatory values
beta <- c(5, 1/2)                       # True coefficients
sigma <- 2                              # Error s.d.
X <- within(X, y <- beta[1] + beta[2] * x + rnorm(nrow(X), 0, sigma))
#
# Fit an OLS model.
#
mod <- lm(y ~ x, X)
#
# Specify the new explanatory variables.
#
X.New <- data.frame(x = seq(3, 8))
#
# Predict the results.
#
X.New$y <- predict(mod, X.New)
#
# Compute the sum of the predictions and their standard error.
#
p.hat <- sum(X.New$y)
v <- colSums(model.matrix(formula(mod), X.New))
se <- sqrt(v %*% vcov(mod) %*% v)
c(`Predicted total` = signif(p.hat, 3),
  `Standard error` = signif(se, 3))
```

Comment: I wonder if you can help me to code it in r?

Comment: Also, I am unclear: vcov(model) is a term that is based on data that is used to build a model, which is different from the data that is used to predict. Why do we use it here?

Comment: Because the uncertainty, according to your question, arises *only* from the random responses in the original data.  If the new explanatory variables are uncertain, that's a different situation altogether and you will need to explain your probability model for them.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: how should i change the formulas if both my x and y are logged? ie the formula is mod <- lm(ln(y) ~ ln(x), X)? I thought I would figure it out: but not sure how to do with sums: cause sums of log numbers is not the same as sum of exponents of those numbers

Comment: There's no difference whatsoever.  All you have done is to change the names of the variables from `x` and `y` to `ln(x)` and `ln(y)`.

Comment: yes, but at the end when i calculate sum of predictions: I have sum of logged values.  for instance I have x=2,3,and 5 . ln(x)= 0.69, 1.61, 1.09. sum of ln(x)= 3.40. if I exponentiate it it gives me 29 which is not equal to sum of x ( 2+5+3=10). same for var-covar matrix

Comment: i made a separate thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73738445/how-to-calculate-uncertainty-in-the-sum-of-the-predictions-for-log-model I shared my data and what I have done to make it easier to reproduce